# Blender Python - I'm unable to assign a hotkey to my plugin

Tags: python, shortcut

I've been developing a Decimate macro plugin for Blender and so far I have all the pieces together fairly well. However, I've been unable to set a hotkey for it using Python. I followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0xBhh47Tblc) but I can't input the idname of the pie menu directly into Blender settings, instead, I have to do it manually. The only thing that goes straight to the *3D View (Global)* menu is the `wm.call_menu_pie` idname:

[image]

Is there any function I can use to input it directly into Blender options using Python?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keybinding for a python script](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/271204/keybinding-for-a-python-script)

Comment: Actually, this didn't work. I tried different variations changing the class names but none of this worked directly and I still have to input the Name manually in the preferences window to make it work.

I tried using VIEW3D_MT_PIE_decimator.bl_idname, changing the bl_idname for "wm.call_menu_pie", didn't work. Tried the other way around and still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this after reading this post:
[Custom pie menu not working with keyboard shortcut anymore](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43693/custom-pie-menu-not-working-with-keyboard-shortcut-anymore)

since my addon consists in a pie menu, I found out that adding the following property to the shortcut is the solution:

```
kmi.properties.name = "VIEW3D_MT_PIE_decimator"
```

in which `"VIEW3D_MT_PIE_decimator"` is the class name of the Pie Menu.